# Matrix equation from optimization problem

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-equations

I am having a problem to find the solution to the following equation which has arisen as part of the solution of a (convex) optimization problem I am considering.
$$\left(\frac{a}{n \ln(\tau)}M^{-1}-x(\mu \bar{r}-\lambda e)^t\right)x=0$$
or rather, with appropriate constants, we can write this in general form
$$(A-xc^t)x=0 $$
where $A$ (and $M$ of the original problem) is positive definite and $x,c \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I need to find $x$.

Also, I am interested in

$$(I-cx^t A)x=0$$

I would very much appreciate any help, references or much better a solution.

EDIT: Screwed my original post, just realized a tensor product xc^t can't be positive definite.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: Thank you, does a similar result hold for $(I-cx^t A)x=0$? Do you have a good source where i could learn more about these problems? My linear algebra courses didn't really cover these things.

Comment: For the new equation: $x$ is a multiple of $c$.

Comment: Thank you very much again. If you wish to submit this as an answer I will clearly accept it. Do you mind me asking how you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Why do you say this is convex? It does not look so to me.

Comment: The problem itself was convex. This is part of the derived dual feasibility equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the first equation $(A - xc^t) x = 0$:**

If $x$ is a solution of that equation, then we have
$$ Ax = x (c^t x). $$
Apart from the trivial solution $x=0$, $x$ needs to be an eigenvector of $A$ and $c^t x$ the corresponding eigenvalue. Let $v$ be an eigenvector to eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then, we have
$$ Av = \lambda v = (c^t v) v. $$
So $x = \frac{\lambda}{c^t v} v$ is a solution, if $c^t v \ne 0$.

**For the second equation $(I - cx^t A) x = 0$:**

If $x$ is a solution of that equation, then we have
$$ x = c (x^t A x). $$
Apart from the trivial solution $x=0$, $x$ needs to be a multiple of $c$.
Assume $x = \mu c$ for some $\mu\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0 \}$ and $c\ne 0$.
Then, we have
$$ \mu c = c \mu^2 (c^t A c). $$
Thus, $\mu = (c^t A c)^{-1}$ and $x = \frac{c}{c^t A c}$.

Comment: Much appreciated. Accepted.